# Sorting an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, typescript

I wish to sort an array of medals. My first sort returns an array sorted according to the gold medals. I then wish to range those which are having the same gold but silver medals are different (same for bronze). I use the following codes that actually makes me run out of memory. This is my code:

```
static sort(data) {
    let sorted = data.sort((a, b) => b.medal.gold - a.medal.gold);
    let next, temp, current;
    for (let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        current = sorted[i].medal;
        if (sorted[i+1]) next = sorted[i+1].medal;
        if (next) {
            if (current.gold === next.gold) {
                if (current.silver < next.silver) {
                    temp = sorted[i+1];
                    sorted[i+1] = sorted[i];
                    sorted[i] = temp;
                }
                else if (current.silver === next.silver) {
                    if (current.bronze < next.bronze) {
                        temp = sorted[i+1];
                        sorted[i+1] = sorted[i];
                        sorted[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: can you please share the array

Comment: Please update your array data into your question for more detailed.

Comment: why do you use `static` in javascript?

Comment: an example would be: ` [{ id: 1, medals: {gold: 2, silver: 1, bronze: 1}}, { id: 2, medals: {gold: 2, silver: 4, bronze: 1} }, { id: 3, medals: {gold: 5, silver: 1, bronze: 4} } ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set **next** to null somewhere, because it keeps the value from the previous iteration and the if(next) is always true. Afterwards the function will always create one more element and add it in the array (sorted[i+1] = sorted[i]) until you run out of memory.

Here is a working example:

```js
var rawData = 
    [{ id: 1, medal: {gold: 2, silver: 1, bronze: 1}}, 
     { id: 2, medal: {gold: 2, silver: 1, bronze: 2} }, 
     { id: 3, medal: {gold: 5, silver: 1, bronze: 4} } ];

function sortData(data) {
    let sorted = data.sort((a, b) => b.medal.gold - a.medal.gold);
    let next, temp, current;
    for (let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        next = undefined;
        current = sorted[i].medal;
        if (sorted[i+1]) next = sorted[i+1].medal;
        if (next) {
            if (current.gold === next.gold) {
                if (current.silver < next.silver) {
                    temp = sorted[i+1];
                    sorted[i+1] = sorted[i];
                    sorted[i] = temp;
                }
                else if (current.silver === next.silver) {
                    if (current.bronze < next.bronze) {
                        temp = sorted[i+1];
                        sorted[i+1] = sorted[i];
                        sorted[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sorted;
};

console.log(sortData(rawData))
```

Please note that in the function you are using **medal** instead of **medals** as the data you have provided in one of your comments.

Comment: Indeed. Well spotted!

Comment: Great. But i am also interested in why the code above does not work.

Comment: Eh... it *is* explained.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to improve your compare function so it takes care of that requirement:

```
data.sort((a, b) => (b.medal.gold - a.medal.gold) 
                 || (b.medal.silver - a.medal.silver) 
                 || (b.medal.bronze - a.medal.bronze) )
```

And then you don't need the (endless) `for` loop at all.